# Error While fetch image from gallary

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-gallery, android-bitmap

I made code as below to get image:

```
private void openFileManager() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    i.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
}
```

And fetch image in **onActivityResult** method as below :

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
iv1.setImageBitmap(b);
```

but get error as :

```
08-04 17:44:36.630 20795-20795/com.test E/image path: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Ffile%2F10750/ORIGINAL/NONE/1807946268
08-04 17:44:36.630 20795-20795/com.test E/image path: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Ffile%2F10750/ORIGINAL/NONE/1807946268
08-04 17:44:36.647 20795-20795/com.test W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
```

Its pointing to the line : `InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);`

I get this error in marshmallow, but not in Kitkat. I feel Google Photo App only return this type of URI in ActivityResult.

Edition : I get to know this is error when Internal Intent call Google Photo app for image selection. Tnx @[Sanket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38767563/5432730). But how to fix this problem. Any code to handle URI from Google Photo and bifercate URI to get pic directly. Because I have to pass it in Glide Library function to render in ImageView.

Comment: Try switching to `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. `ACTION_PICK` is for picking a piece of content from a specific collection. For choosing content based on MIME type, use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

Comment: its still same error @CommonsWare. and one more problem i get is if i use ACTION_GET_CONTENT then it show all file even if its image or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code for image fetching in android 5,6

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                getLocalContext().getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        return image;
    }
```

getLocalContext() is you local context.

Comment: great ! this ParcelFileDescriptor and FileDescriptor worked for me. tnx.

Comment: I get File not found exception in kitkat

Answer (score 1):

it's exception while fetching google photos.you can use this [class](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java#L202) to get it.

You need to copy this 2 classes [FileUtils](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java) and [LocalStorageProvider](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ianhanniballake/localstorage/LocalStorageProvider.java) into your project and you can get file in onActiyityResult using this method

```
File mPhotoFile = FileUtils.getFile(this, data.getData());
```

it will work in all OS version and weather you are using ***document*** directory or ***media*** directory.

Comment: I don't know why this answer is downvoted. You can use the line of code he pointed to.

Comment: Hi. Can u say me if I get true in return from the method u pointed out then how can I use that uri to fetch image ? @sanket

Comment: @Sanket how can i add the library you pointed out in gradle ?

Comment: @Dharvikshah is your problem solved or still do you need to integrate this library?

Comment: its get solve by ParcelFileDescriptor and FileDescriptor. But tnx. but i really want to know gradle line for the library you mention. is any compile code for that?

Comment: @Dharvikshah i have edited my answer. this class is well written for all version and also for remote Uri.

Comment: Hi from where i can find FileUtils class. if its need to import any library in gradle then can you please give me dependency line ?

Comment: no need for any dependency. just copy mentioned class in your project and you can able to access their static methods which i have given in answer.

Comment: actually i have done that before and now also. i get error as : Cannot resolve symbol 'LocalStorageProvider'. when i check import then it show error in line : import com.ianhanniballake.localstorage.LocalStorageProvider;